# watch not working when setValue sets nested objects

Tags: react-hook-form

I pass a complete object to setValue and the input box is updated correctly, but my watch is not printing:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const form = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      detail: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: ""
      }
    }
  });
  console.log("watch:", form.watch("detail.firstName"));

  const setValueWhole = () => {
    form.setValue("detail", {
      firstName: "firstName",
      lastName: "lastName"
    });
  };

  const setValueEach = () => {
    form.setValue("detail.firstName", "firstName1");
    form.setValue("detail.lastName", "lastName1");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(console.log)}>
        <input {...form.register("detail.firstName")} />
        <input {...form.register("detail.lastName")} />
        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={setValueWhole}>
            setValue whole
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={setValueEach}>
            setValue each
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Initially, the console printed:

```bash
watch: ""
```

Clicking the `setValue whole` button, the value of the input box is updated, but the console is not printing again, am I doing something wrong?

```bash
watch: ""
# Nothing prints after clicking...
```

---

If I click `setValue each`, it will print correctly:

```bash
watch: ""
watch: "firstName1"
```